# Spring cloud netflix turbine.stream reports no data

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, netflix, hystrix

Like a few others before me, I cannot get hystrix streams reported by my services to be aggregated by turbine (local, not amqp). I have read all the questions and answers here on SO, applied their advice and have got nowhere. Here's my setup.

Version: Brixton M4
Services running on localhost: eureka, zuul, myservice, myservice2, turbine

myservice and myservice2 are microservices that expose `hystrix.stream`. As with zuul, I can connect directly to these `hystrix.stream` endpoints and see data. `turbine.stream` is always empty.

**turbine application.yml**

The turbine part of this configuration is taken almost directly from the example in the spring cloud docs.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: turbine

server:
  port: 8989

management:
  port: 8990

turbine:
  aggregator:
    clusterNameExpression: metadata['cluster']
    clusterConfig: LOCAL
  appConfig: myservice,myservice2,zuul
  InstanceMonitor:
    eventStream:
      skipLineLogic:
        enabled: false

eureka:
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 10
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/

info:
  component: Turbine!
```

**Each of the 3 services includes:**

```
eureka:
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 10
    metadataMap:
      cluster: LOCAL
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

**Verifying that the metadata map is correct in Eureka from http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps**

```
<applications>
  <versions__delta>1</versions__delta>
  <apps__hashcode>UP_4_</apps__hashcode>
  <application>
    <name>MYSERVICE</name>
    <instance>
      <instanceId>192.168.43.128:myservice:2222</instanceId>
      <hostName>192.168.43.128</hostName>
      <app>MYSERVICE</app>
      <ipAddr>192.168.43.128</ipAddr>
      <status>UP</status>
      <overriddenstatus>UNKNOWN</overriddenstatus>
      <port enabled="true">2222</port>
      <securePort enabled="false">443</securePort>
      <countryId>1</countryId>
      <dataCenterInfo class="com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo">
        <name>MyOwn</name>
      </dataCenterInfo>
      <leaseInfo>
        <renewalIntervalInSecs>10</renewalIntervalInSecs>
        <durationInSecs>90</durationInSecs>
        <registrationTimestamp>1453382031096</registrationTimestamp>
        <lastRenewalTimestamp>1453382630966</lastRenewalTimestamp>
        <evictionTimestamp>0</evictionTimestamp>
        <serviceUpTimestamp>1453382031096</serviceUpTimestamp>
      </leaseInfo>
      <metadata>
        <cluster>LOCAL</cluster>
      </metadata>
```

When I run turbine it is finding the service instances in Eureka but is not choosing them to report data:

```
o.s.c.n.t.CommonsInstanceDiscovery       : Fetching instance list for apps: [myservice, myservice2, zuul]
o.s.c.n.turbine.EurekaInstanceDiscovery  : Fetching instances for app: myservice
o.s.c.n.turbine.EurekaInstanceDiscovery  : Received instance list for app: myservice, size=1
o.s.c.n.turbine.EurekaInstanceDiscovery  : Fetching instances for app: myservice2
o.s.c.n.turbine.EurekaInstanceDiscovery  : Received instance list for app: myservice2, size=1
o.s.c.n.turbine.EurekaInstanceDiscovery  : Fetching instances for app: zuul
o.s.c.n.turbine.EurekaInstanceDiscovery  : Received instance list for app: zuul, size=1
c.n.t.discovery.InstanceObservable       : Retrieved hosts from InstanceDiscovery: 3
c.n.t.discovery.InstanceObservable       : Found hosts that have been previously terminated: 0
```

And another (potentially useful?) log line that appears when logging is raised to `DEBUG`:

```
c.n.t.discovery.InstanceObservable       : Retrieved hosts from InstanceDiscovery: [StatsInstance [hostname=192.168.43.128, cluster: MYSERVICE, isUp: true, attrs={cluster=LOCAL, port=2222}], StatsInstance [hostname=192.168.43.128, cluster: MYSERVICE2, isUp: true, attrs={cluster=LOCAL, port=2223}], StatsInstance [hostname=192.168.43.128, cluster: ZUUL, isUp: true, attrs={cluster=LOCAL, port=8765}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

OK never mind, it was a silly mistake on my part that I spotted while running turbine in the debugger. `clusterNameExpression` is a child of `turbine` and not `aggregator`.

With that error corrected I can see the first service in the comma separated list reporting data in the turbine stream but not the others. Is this expected? i.e. Is turbine designed for monitoring the streams from multiple microservices that make up the same logical application or is it purely for multiple instances of the same microservice?